# Removing files that are older than some number of days

Tags: c#

I guess this is a pretty common requirement in a application that does quite a bit of logging. I am working on a C# Windows application, .NET 3.5.

My app generates tons of log files which has a current date put in the file name like so 20091112. What would be the best strategy to remove files older than say 30 days. 
One approach I am about to use it, is to loop through the file names, extract the date part, convert into DateTime object and compare with today's date. 
Is there an elegant Regular Expression solution to this :) ? Or something better?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\log").GetFiles("*.log");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (DateTime.UtcNow - file.CreationTimeUtc > TimeSpan.FromDays(30))
    {
        File.Delete(file.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just that I have to get all the FileInfo objects in memory to do this. I was thinking of getting just the names since it has the date in it. Does this sound reasonable though?

Comment: I guess you could interop with `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` API or take a look at .NET 4.0 where you could use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` which returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`.

Comment: FileInfo objects arent that heavy - they're not a file handle or anything. PowerShell uses them for directory entries flowing through a pipeline for instance.

Comment: what if we wanna say older than couple hours or years? is there something like TimeSpan.FromYears or TimeSpan.FromHours? if there is it would be such an easy thing to do also +1 for simplicity

Comment: @BerkerYüceer, there is `TimeSpan.FromHours`.

Answer (score 13):

**update .net 4.0:**

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath).GetFiles("*.log");
foreach (var file in files.Where(file => DateTime.UtcNow - file.CreationTimeUtc > TimeSpan.FromHours(2))) {
     file.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string directoryPath = "/log"; // your log directory path

foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetCreationTime(directoryPath))
{
    TimeSpan fileAge = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath) - DateTime.Now;
    if (fileAge.Days > 30)
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to use file name rather than modification time. Fine.

Then the code is like this:

```
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        string fileNameOnly=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        DateTime fileDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fileNameOnly, "yyyyMMDD", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileDate).TotalDays > MaxDays)
            File.Delete(file);
    }
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I have in my code now. I just had a thought, I have a date pattern in a set of strings which I need to compare, I might be able to employ Regex, but seems that I need to go the foreach loop way.

Answer (score 1):

[In PowerShell] you could paste the following into a PS1 file and make it part of an admin script if that suits:-

> param($path=$(throw "Need to indicate path"), $daysToRetain=$(throw "Need to indicate how many days to retain"))
>
> dir $path -r  | ? { ([datetime]::UtcNow - $_.CreationTimeUtc).TotalDays -gt $daysToRetain } | del

EDIT: And you can use `-match` to parse the name if you feel using the file times isnt the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Substracting two `DateTime` objects will give you a `TimeSpan` object, then you can just check its `TotalDays` property. I can't think of anything simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (string file in files)
 {
  if (File.GetLastWriteTime(file) < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5))
    {
      File.Delete(file);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation, not only raw code in your answers. You might also want to explain what is it, that your answer adds to the existing answers.