# Delete files which are older than today's date

Tags: c#, arrays, string, datetime, split

I have some files in the format of "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_abc.txt" in a particular location.
using the below code i am able to get all the files with "_abc.txt" in that folder.

```
fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C://Documents", "*abc.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
{
    fileArray[i] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileArray[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(fileArray[i]);
}
```

But now I'm thinking of reading the file name, split it and then convert into date time object so that i can check for the condition(older than today's date) and delete them.

> ```
> for eg: 20160426_045823_abc.txt
> ```

I want to split it into 2016, 04 , 26 and then convert into date time object using 
`Datetime d1 = new Datetime(2016,04,26)` and then do other operations.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing files that are older than some number of days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720790/removing-files-that-are-older-than-some-number-of-days)

Comment: @KenWhite It's not a duplicate. That other question is based on file creation time, and this one is about date-embedded-in-filename.

Answer (score 2):

The following code can be used to get the collection of files having created date less than today's date, A simple iteration over the collection will help you to delete them as well: consider the code

Simple option:

```
foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(@"C://Documents", "*.txt")
                               .Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date  < DateTime.Now.Date))
{
    File.Delete(item);
}
```

Based on Filename:

```
var fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C://Documents", "*abc.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
{
    DateTime fileNameTime;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileArray[i]).Replace("_abc", " ");
    fileNameTime = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", fileName, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    if (fileNameTime.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        File.Delete(fileArray[i]);
    }
}
```

> **Please note :** The best and effective option is the first one, what you need to do is assign the file-name as the dateTime at the time of
>   creation of the file(if it is under your control) so that the things
>   became easier for you

Comment: Probably want to use CreationTime.Date and DateTime.Now.Date, unless you want to delete all files :)

Comment: @gnalck: thankk you, nice spot. i have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
i'm looking for the file name more than the creation time.

Comment: @un-lucky here we are jus comparing if the date is less than todays date. what if i have to check for 5 days older condition? 

I tried this:

            if (DateTime.Now.Date - d5.Date > TimeSpan.FromDays(5))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileArray[i]);
                File.Delete(fileArray[i]);
            }

But the file is not getting deleted. anything to tweak in here?

Comment: use `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).Date` instead for `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 2):

The filename is already in a sortable format based on the date. Instead of parsing bits of the filename into a DateTime object, why not create a filename based on today's date and filter your array of filenames down to only those that are string-comparison-less than your today's-date filename? It's probably quite a bit faster than doing date parsing on each filename, for large lists of files.

For example:

```
var path = "c:\\whatever";
var suffix = "_abc.txt";
var todaysFilename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + suffix;
var filesToDelete = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*" + suffix)
    .Select(Path.GetFileName)
    .Where(fileName => string.Compare(fileName, todaysFilename, StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0)
    .ToArray();

foreach (var file in filesToDelete)
{
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(path, file));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if i have to delete files which are 5 days older than today's date? Is it 5 instead of 0 in your code?

Comment: No, the `Compare` function returns a value less than zero when the first argument is less, zero when they're equal, and a value greater than zero when the second argument is less. What you want to do is this: `var todayFilename = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString(...)`. That would delete all files more than 5 days old.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the name of the string and do a DateTime.ParseExact.

```
String dateString = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileArray[i])
DateTime d5 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
if (d5.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    File.Delete(fileArray[i]);
}
```

This will take the first 8 characters of the string and parse do an exact parse on it.
Also you will probably just want the filename without the path and extension.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If the creation date is the date that you want to compare the other answers are probably better, but if the date in the filename is what you want and not the actual creation date then parsing the date from the string is better.

Comment: Hi Arina.. i tried your method. but it is throwing an error.. 
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

After getting the filenames i did this.

 DateTime d5 = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd", fileArray[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
 Console.WriteLine(d5);

Comment: You will probably have to truncate the filename to get it in to the exact format.
DateTime d5 = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd", fileArray[i].SubString(0, 8), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)

Comment: Hi Arina..is there any reference to be added for stringtool? because it shows no potential fixes for the same. TIA

Comment: Sorry, I meant to Substring, was just copy and pasting from some code.

Comment: i think u need to tweak your answer  a little bit. 

DateTime d5 = DateTime.ParseExact(filename,"yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DateTime a file was created like this

```
DateTime time = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);
```

Yes it's that easy.

Comment: hi JSON. When i tried this code, why is it showing 1/1/1601 8:00:00 AM as the creation date. Is there anything else i need to do/

Comment: Your fileName is probably not correct.  Make sure you include the entire path.  If you like my answer mark as answered and thumps me up